# PHP MySQL Query Select Count

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am having a problem with the following query that should count Null and Not Empty records in database. I need to use a prepared statement to execute. I have the following code but I cant get the correct output. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
$query = "SELECT UserName, COUNT(NULLIF(TRIM(UserName), ''))
FROM    Employee";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query7);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->bind_result($Count);
    for ($i=0; $i <$numrows; $i++) {
        $stmt->fetch();

        echo "Count: $Count";
    };
```

Comment: Your query counts non-Null and non-empty records.

Comment: Why are you also selecting `UserName`? That will just pick an arbitrary username from the table. Why do you use a loop to print the results, since there's just one row with the total for the entire table. Did you mean to group the data in some way?

Comment: Please show some sample data and the expected output.

Comment: I am actually trying to count the values that are NOT NULL and NOT EMPTY.  I just need a single 'total' number to display. I guess I don't really need a loop to print the results then. I don't need to group the data, I just need to count how many records in the table have the defined value 'UserName'.

Comment: I also just tried this but still no output  `$result=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(UserName IS NOT NULL OR TRIM(UserName) != '') FROM Employee");
    $Count=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo "Total: $Count";`

Comment: `mysql_fetch_assoc` returns an associative array, you can't echo an array. Use `var_dump($Count)`.

Comment: Or give an alias to the column, like `AS count`, and echo `$Count['count']`.

Comment: Why have you switched from mysqli to the obsolete mysql?

Comment: I am kind of struggling with this. I tried this, is this the right approach?  `$query = "SELECT SUM(UserName IS NOT NULL OR TRIM(UserName) != '') AS Count FROM Employee";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $numrows = $stmt->num_rows;
    $stmt->bind_result($Count['Count']);
    echo "Count: $Count";`

Comment: You seem to be confusing all the different ways of getting results. If you use `bind_result`, you don't use an associative array.

Comment: See my answer for the full code.

Comment: What have you tried? What exactly is going wrong? Do you get any errors? What are those errors? What have you tried to do to fix those errors? What happened when you did that? Remember to include these things when you make your question. Follow this guide to make sure your questions are of high quality: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count non-null and non-empty records, you can do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Employee
WHERE UserName IS NOT NULL AND UserName != ''
```

You don't need to use `TRIM(UserName)`, because trailing spaces are ignored when comparing strings.

The full PHP code should be like this:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(*)
            FROM Employee
            WHERE UserName IS NOT NULL AND UserName != ''";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->bind_result($Count);
$stmt->fetch();
echo "Count: $Count";
```